# DynamoDB: Query a secondary index with prefix (begins_with) only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to a DynamoDB query for a string that's not a part of the primary key and I only have this string.

As an example I have

```
Music
  Artist: String, PrimaryKey(HASH)
  SongTitle: String, PrimaryKey(RANGE)
  AlbumTitle: String, GlobalSecondaryKey(probably RANGE)
```

and I want to query "all Music items that have AlbumTitle starts with 'Some'".

I tried this with aws cli

### create table (still with HASH for AlbumTitle)

```sh
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name Music \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=Artist,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=SongTitle,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=AlbumTitle,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=Artist,KeyType=HASH \
        AttributeName=SongTitle,KeyType=RANGE \
    --provisioned-throughput \
        ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
    --global-secondary-indexes \
        "[
            {
                \"IndexName\": \"AlbumTitle-Index\",
                \"KeySchema\": [{\"AttributeName\":\"AlbumTitle\",\"KeyType\":\"HASH\"}],
                \"Projection\":{ \"ProjectionType\":\"ALL\" },
                \"ProvisionedThroughput\":{
                    \"ReadCapacityUnits\": 1,
                    \"WriteCapacityUnits\": 1
                }
            }
        ]"
```

wait until

```sh
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Music | grep IndexStatus
```

responds

```
 "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
```

### put some items

```sh
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Music  \
    --item '{"Artist": {"S": "No One You Know"}, "SongTitle": {"S": "Call Me Today"}, "AlbumTitle": {"S": "Somewhat Famous"}, "Awards": {"N": "1"}}'
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Music  \
    --item '{"Artist": {"S": "No One You Know"}, "SongTitle": {"S": "Call Me Tomorrow"}, "AlbumTitle": {"S": "Something Famous"}, "Awards": {"N": "1"}}'
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Music \
    --item '{"Artist": {"S": "Acme Band"}, "SongTitle": {"S": "Happy Day"}, "AlbumTitle": {"S": "Songs About Life"}, "Awards": {"N": "10"} }'
```

### query with equal (works)

```sh
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name Music \
    --index-name AlbumTitle-Index \
    --key-condition-expression "AlbumTitle = :name" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":name":{"S":"Somewhat Famous"}}'
```

### query with begins_with (does not work)

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name Music \
    --index-name AlbumTitle-Index \
    --key-condition-expression "begins_with(AlbumTitle, :name)" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":name":{"S":"Some"}}'
```

results in

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported
```

Ok. That does not work, because I created the index `AlbumTitle-Index` with AlbumTitle(**HASH**). Hence I only can query equals.

### problem / question

What do I need to change that I can perform a prefix search? I only find `begins_with` and everywhere it's combined with a HASH key as its first part. I don't have anything but the string that should be matched as a prefix in `AlbumTitle`.
I cannot simply replace `HASH` with `RANGE` in the `AlbumTutle-Index` like

```
    --global-secondary-indexes \
        "[
            {
                \"IndexName\": \"AlbumTitle-Index\",
                \"KeySchema\": [{\"AttributeName\":\"AlbumTitle\",\"KeyType\":\"RANGE\"}],
                ...
```

because of

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: Invalid KeySchema: The first KeySchemaElement is not a HASH key type
```

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but for anyone reading this: if you're querying by partition key (GSI or not) you must ask for equality. *If* you have a sort key, you can then apply some fun functions to its condition. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)

What OP did to solve their problem is effectively that: it turned the primary key to a equality/hashable comparison. Which is the DynamoDB way of solving issues.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a new field that holds only the first digit of the AlbumTitle named `AlbumTitleForHash` and this will be the hash key for the GSI.

Then I can query for `AlbumTitleHash=<first digit of query>` and `AlbumTitle=<query>`